# Is making a post request inside a get route unRESTful?

Tags: javascript, express, restful-authentication

In the code below my express server is handling a get request coming from a weather app. A function is called when the page initially loads to get the location. However, the api I am using, 'geolocation', uses a post request to get location data.

Is is unRESTful for me to be making a post request inside my get route like this?

```
router.get('/', function(req,res ){
    axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=${googleGeo}`, {
        considerIp: "true",
    })
    .then((data) => {
        return {'lat': data.data.location.lat, 'lng':data.data.location.lng }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
  })
});
```

Comment: Not at all. Your GET route is doing some work. RESTful doesn't care about it.

Comment: It'd be unrestful if you were doing a POST to your same app.

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but note that the sender IP of the request to the Google API will be your Node server's, and not the originating client's. The client's IP would be accessible via [`req.ip`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip) (if using ExpressJS, which you are), but I don't think Google's API lets you pass it in. You may need another API if this'll be a problem.

Comment: thank you all for the advice.  Tavnab, you have confirmed my suspicions

Answer (score 0):

As long as your API toward your client is RESTful in how it presents its resources, it shouldn't matter how you get/store/manage that data in the backend, at least as far as REST is concerned.

That said, don't forget to send a response (e.g. `res.json({lat:..., lng:...})`) instead of returning from your `.then()` handler, and to send an error status code (e.g. `res.sendStatus(500)`) in your `.catch()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't get hung up on the word `post`, especially when you're using someone else's API. What matters is that when someone makes a `GET` request, **it should not mutate state**. In your case, the API probably uses the `POST` method so that you don't need to stick the request object into the query string or perhaps due to size limits of `GET` requests. It's just getting geo data - not mutating state.

If it mutates state, it should be a `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE`. If it's really read only, `GET` is always appropriate, regardless of the APIs you're calling underneath the hood.